# Graficar funciones

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Estaba programando gráficas de funciones pero aún no resuelvo como marcar el eje `Y` al eje `X`.

Probé con algunos frameworks como chart js canvas y no obtengo resultados.

Comment: Por favor pone parte del codigo que intentaste para que podamos ver que error te da o que falta. Si dejas la pregunta asi la van a tirar abajo porque no sigue los pasos de como formular una pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Te recomiendo  `paper.js` en el puedes manejar canvas y coordenadas, quizas te sea util